# Using ViewController Class as Parameter in a method

Tags: ios, viewcontroller

Good day. I'm new to iOS. I'm creating a static library, and I have a method that accepts a viewcontroller so, i imported uikit in the header like this.

myclass.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
```

and in my implementation class i have this method that would accept view controller, however I could only have UIViewController class.

myclass.m

```
- (void) initializeLocationManager: (CLLocationManager *) locationManager fromViewController: (UIViewController *) view{

    locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
    locationManager.delegate = view;
}
```

so i get a warning: Assigning to 'id' from incompatible type 'UIViewController *_strong.

Please help. THank you.

Comment: Where is the warning showing in your file? Is it on the above line -(void) initializeLoca.... or is it somewhere else?

Comment: Also, what kind of object is myclass.h?

Answer (score 0):

First, stylistically, your variable shouldn't be `view` if it is a viewController, but that won't cause an error or warning, it is just confusing for people who read the code.

Second, you are passing in a `locationManager` variable, but over writing it, so it serves no purpose.

Finally, the reason you are getting the warning is because the `delegate` property of `CLLocationManager` is declared as `id<CLLocationManagerDelegate>`, but you are assigning a UIViewController.  Now, it might be that your particular UIViewController instances implements the `CLLocationManagerDelegate` but the compiler doesn't know that so it issues a warning.  If all goes well at runtime it will work, but if someone passes a UIViewController instance that *doesn't* implement `CLLocationManagerDelegate` you may get an exception when the location manager tries to invoke a delegate method.

You should write -

```
- (CLLocationManager *) initializeLocationManagerWithDelegate:(id<CLLocationManagerDelegate>) delegate {

   CLLocationManager *manager=[[CLLocationManager alloc]init];
   manager.delegate=delegate;

   return manager;
}
```